# UniVocity howto add parameters to a custom Validator

Tags: java, validation, univocity

I'm creating some custom Validators for univocity parser and I want to add some parameters like this:

```java
   public class Size implements Validator<String>
   int max;
```

and then use it like this:

```java
   @Parsed
   @Validate(nullable = false, validators = Size.class(8) )
   private String someString;
```

I didn't found anything like this or examples with annotations.

Maybe using javax.validation annotations?

Or maybe injecting sizeValidation object created with range limit constructor?

Thanks!

Comment: Partially solved. Size could be validated with RegEx ^_^  `matches = "^.{3,5}$"` size min=3, max=5

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Two options here:

1 - add the annotations on a setter (simple but not reusable:

```
    @Parsed
    @Validate(nullable = false)
    public void setSomeString(String value){
        if(value.length() < 3 || value.length() > 5){
            throw new DataValidationException("SomeString can't have length " + value.length());
        }
        this.someString = value;
    }
```

2 - extend class `ValidatedConversion` and use that class on a `@Convert` annotation:

```
public class LengthValidator extends ValidatedConversion {

    private int min;
    private int max;

    public LengthValidator(String... args) {
        super(false, false); //not null / not blank
        this.min = Integer.parseInt(args[0]);
        this.max = Integer.parseInt(args[1]);
    }

    @Override
    protected void validate(Object value) {
        super.validate(value); //let super check for null and whatever you need.
        String string = value.toString();
        if(string.length() < min || string.length() > max){
            throw new com.univocity.parsers.common.DataValidationException("Value can't have length " + string.length());
        }
    }
}
```

Then add it to your attribute:

```
    @Parsed
    @Convert(conversionClass = LengthValidator.class, args = {"3", "5"})
    private String someString;
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: It helps a lot. Thanks! excellent library btw. I'm combining RegEx with ValidatedConversion and it works ... fast! :-)